# Why doesn't Cantor's diagonal proof work if we consider each binary tuple to be a base-2 integer?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

So, I understand how Cantor's diagonal argument works for infinite sequences of binary digits.  I also know it doesn't apply to natural numbers since they "zero out". However, what if we treated each sequence of binary digits in the original argument, as an integer in base-2? In that case, the newly produced sequence is just another integer, and integers are countable.

Comment: There is no integer corresponding to $(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots)$

Comment: @0XLR Why tho? If we can say 99999... with infinitely many 9s is an integer, then why can't 1111111... correspond to an integer? Are there any rigorous proofs for it?

Comment: Each natural number has finitely many nonzero bits base $2$.  Prove that by induction.

Comment: Yes, we *can* say that $99999\dots$ with infinitely many $9$'s is an integer, but nevertheless that statement is false.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see. So if it's not an integer, then is it just a real number? Is it even considered rational or irrational?

Comment: It's nothing. There is no real number whose decimal representations consists of $99999\dots$ with infinitely many $9$'s.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ok I understand. Thanks

Comment: This is why we have to be precise about what is included in our number systems- you can run into paradoxes otherwise

Comment: So there is a way to make sense out of ...99999 as a number, although when you do this you get things much more exotic than natural numbers or even real numbers. I sort of hesitated to mention this, because it feels like saying "sure, you can throw open the door and step out of an airplane flying at 10,000 feet", and it's hard to give enough emphasis to the fact that you really, really, really need a parachute, and you need to be similarly careful interpreting ...999999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't mean to be condescending here, but to handle formal math you need to let go of many things you thought were true when you learned about them in elementary school. And that can be hard to do, even for some Mathematicians.

Here is one of those things: 4321 is not a number. It is a character string. It can be used as the decimal representation of an actual integer, in which case it means 4*10^3 + 3*10^3 + 2*10 + 1, where all these symbols are also character strings that represent numbers.

This works for real numbers as well. 3.141... is not the number we call "pi." It is another character sting. It also can be a decimal representation of "pi" if we correctly extend the string infinitely. This time it means 3 + 1*10^(-1) + 4*10^(-2) + 1*10^(-3) + ... . But in order *prove* that this is a number, we need to prove that the sequence [10^(-1), 10^(-2), 10^(-3), ...] converges to zero. Which is pretty trivial.

Finally, ...99999 is also a string - and please notice how I wrote it differently than it was in a previous comment. But this string can't be used as the decimal representation of an actual integer, because you can't formulate that summation for it. You can't identify the "n" that is represents the largest power of 10. So the sequence [10^0, 10^1, 10^2, ...] does not converge.

And the same idea applies in base 2.